# Select from array only the best items

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting

I am strugling to come up with a linq statement where i want to select only some items in an array that have the highest version.
Given an array of Apps, for example:

```
[{name="Adobe", version=1},
{name="Adobe", version=2},
{name="Adobe", version=3},
{name="VLC", version=1},
{name="VLC", version=2},
{name="VLC", version=3}]
```

I need a linq to select only 1 adobe app, the one with the highest version, and 1 VLC app.
The result should look like:

```
[{name="Adobe", version=3},
{name="VLC", version=3}]
```

The best i got so far is:

```
var names = apps.Select((n => n.name)).Distinct();
foreach (var name in names)
{
    var latest = apps.Where(n => n.name == name).OrderByDescending(n => n.version).FirstOrDefault();
    //add latest to the new appList
}
```

I keep on thinking whether is there a simpler, linq only way to do this. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What would you want to happen if there was another app ("Notepad") with versions 1-4? Would you want Adobe and VLC v3 as well?

Comment: Do you know about the [Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach:

```
var latest = apps.GroupBy(i => i.Name)
                 .Select(i => i.OrderByDescending(j => j.Version).First());
```

Comment: [Too late](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27019841/284240) ;-) It's also not simpler but different.

Comment: @tim-schmelter Doh! You beat me fair and square. (I'm just trying to get to 15 so I can vote up correct answers.)

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like this:

```
var latest = apps.GroupBy(x=>x.name)
                 .Select(x=> new 
                 { 
                     Name=x.Key, 
                     Version = x.OrderByDescending(y=>y.version)
                                .First().version
                 });
```

Initially, we make a `GroupBy` the name of the app. Then we select the item of each group, with the latest version.

Comment: at the end I think you want `.First().version`

Comment: What if there were another attribute that you needed to include... something like a ReleaseDate or DownloadSize property?

Comment: Could you not do Version = x.Max(y => y.version) ?

Comment: Jonesy is right.  As it is now, it's asking for the first item where version is true, which mean it shouldn't compile as version isn't a boolean.

Comment: @TimSchmelter his desired output looks like the same type as his input

Comment: @TimSchmelter No he doesn't, he's returning a new object array with the name and version.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take:

```
void Main()
{
    var apps = new NameVersion[]
    {
        new NameVersion {name="Adobe", version=1},
        new NameVersion {name="Adobe", version=2},
        new NameVersion {name="Adobe", version=3},
        new NameVersion {name="VLC", version=1},
        new NameVersion {name="VLC", version=2},
        new NameVersion {name="VLC", version=3}
    };


    var q = from a in apps
            group a by a.name into g
            select new NameVersion { name=g.Key, version = g.Max(a=> a.version)};

    q.Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enumerable.GroupBy`:

```
IEnumerable<SomeClass> latest = apps
    .GroupBy(n => n.name)
    .Select(nameGroup => nameGroup.OrderByDescending(n => n.version).First());
```

Answer (score 0):

For small collection with Max() and without (Select+GroupBy()):

```
var list = apps.ToList();
var res = list.Where(
                    x => list.Where(elem=>elem.name == x.name)
                             .Max(elem=>elem.version) == x.version);
```